# Why does my html body move to the left every time I refresh?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, absolute, visual-glitch

This is one of the weirdest bugs I've ever encountered. Some chance it's an extension or a browser bug or something but it only shows up on the app I'm building when I'm refreshing it in development mode, so stackoverflow seems like the right place to start asking.

Basically under certain as-yet-unknown circumstances, every time I reload the page I'm working on, the `<body>` element slides off the page to the left about 10px. And then when I refresh again it often slides even further. If I open the page in a new tab, it's fine.

In this screenshot below, I've highlighted the `<body>` element in the element inspector.

[image: screenshot of Complice UI with interface slid off to the left]

Clues:

- it only happens sometimes, but once it happens almost every refresh increases the offset
- certain absolutely-positioned elements like the navbar continue to fill the whole width of the html element, but others don't
- the body element doesn't have any styles or classes it shouldn't have
- changing the body element position to absolute doesn't affect it
- the html element and the body element are still the same width
- I'm using a 4k screen on linux (?!)

My best guess is something like... it's double-loading some sort of AngularJS directive, although I neither know why it would do that nor why that would cause this bizarre problem. At any rate, likely I'll be the one to solve this, some months or years from now, but if you've got any ideas, I'm curious!

Comment: I have had this same bug usually in Chrome browser on windows OS, every time I update my `css` file the front-page looks like a cache is pre-loaded incorrectly. Another way to reproduce this error is reload the webpage when you are inside `inspect element`. How do I solved ? I switch to ubuntu 20.04 then I tried using `incognito mode`  and I didn't receive the same bug once again. of course this is really radically solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on my website and have had the same problem. However I noticed something: this was only a problem with pages whose css used the 'vw' length attribute. No problems with % or 'vh' though. Maybe check for any 'vw' and try to remove them. Worked for me.